# Mocking a class with parameters in C# Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, moq

How to mock a class with parameters in c# moq

In my code like this

```
public  DataService<TDBContext> : IDataService<TDBContext> where TDBContext : DbContext {
   public readonly TDBContext dbContext;
   public DataService(TDBContext context ) {
     dbContext = context;
   }

   public async Task<T> CreateAsync<T> {
     //.....
   }
}
```

I want to set up  "CreateAsync" method  to return a T instance.
but i also need to support like `dbcontext.Query<Entity>(x=>x.a==1&&x.b=="dd").AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()`, so i use sqlite dbcontext instance.
I mock DataService with constructor's  parameters by moq ( version 4.18) .
output :

```
Type to mock DataService<DBContext> must be an interface , adelegate ,or a non-sealed....
```

If i mock interface without constructor's parameters， i can not initialize dbcontext.

```
var dataService = new Mock<IDataService<TDBContext>>();  // without dbcontext
```

Comment: You can Mock the interface `IDataService` and setup needed methods, or you can create a test class inheriting from `DataService` using your sqlite's dbcontext, in this case, you should to invoke base `DataService` constructor and send your sqlite's dbcontext as parameter.

Comment: You are mocking, so there is no context. Using a test double means that you replace the original class with something else.

Comment: Can you change `public readonly TDBContext dbContext;` to a get-only autoproperty `public TDBContext DBContext { get; }` and then include it in the interface? Then mock the interface.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen No, I can't because I can't change the code for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need in-memory database not moq.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

public static class InMemroy
{
    public static DbContextOptions CreateOptions<T>() where T : DbContext
    {
        //This creates the SQLite connection string to in-memory database
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
                { DataSource = ":memory:" };
        var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();

        //This creates a SqliteConnectionwith that string
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);

        //The connection MUST be opened here
        connection.Open();

        //Now we have the EF Core commands to create SQLite options
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>();
        builder.UseSqlite(connection);

        return builder.Options;
    }
}

        var options = InMemroy.CreateOptions<MyContext>();
        //I create an instance of my DbContext
        using (var context = new MyContext(options))
        {
            //You have to create the database
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            context.SeedDatabaseFourBooks(); 

            var service = new DataService(context);
            service.CreateAsync<Dog>();
        });
```

---

EDIT

@dani herrera Yeah, I don't think he knows what he wants.

Unit tests are designed to validate the smallest possible unit of code, such as a function or a method, and test it in isolation from the rest of the system.

eg.

```cs
public class AnimalService
{
    private readonly AnimalDbContext _context;

    public AnimalService(AnimalDbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public string GetDogName()
    {
        return _context.Dogs.FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
    }

    public Dog Add(Dog dog)
    {
        var result = _context.Dogs.Add(dog);

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return result;
    }
}

[TestMethod()]
public void TestAdd_Save_ReturnsNew()
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Dog>>();

    var mockContext = new Mock<AnimalDbContext>();

    mockContext.Setup(x => x.Dogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var service = new AnimalService(mockContext.Object);

    service.Add(new Dog());

    mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Dog>()), Times.Once);

    mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
}

[TestMethod()]
public void TestGetDogName_SingleElement_ReturnsRex()
{
    const string DOGNAME_RESULT = "Rex";

    var data = new List<Dog>
    {
        new Dog { Name = DOGNAME_RESULT }
    }.AsQueryable();

    Mock<DbSet<Dog>> mockSet = MockHelper.BuildMockDbSet(data);

    var mockContext = new Mock<AnimalDbContext>();

    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Dogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    var service = new AnimalService(mockContext.Object);

    // Arrange
    var dogName = service.GetDogName();

    var actual = DOGNAME_RESULT;

    Assert.AreEqual(actual, dogName);
}
```

Comment: [I'm sorry, was that in your opinion?](https://tenor.com/ca/view/the-good-wife-in-your-opinion-gif-4998493)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You're right, but the code situation is somewhat complicated. I have to use moq.